# Import data from SQL to Excel getting error what to do?

Tags: sql, excel, ssis

I have a database, want to import it to Excel.
 I have used the import wizard in sql server and get this error:

```
Error 0xc0204016: SSIS.Pipeline: The "Data Conversion 6 - 0.Outputs[Data Conversion Output].Columns[conttext]" has a length that is not valid. The length must be between 0 and 4000.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0204016 (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap)
```

Can't figure out what is wrong.

I have identified that the problem is varchar()>4000 and I have 100 of them. How will I convert them to go through the export wizard without problem?

Comment: I think I have identified the problem is with datatype varchar(7878). How to handle it?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the excel source and go to advanced editor.  On the tab, input and output properties, on the external columns and output columns, change the datatype for the column to NTEXT on both.